# python bytes.decode() unable to decode git object

Tags: python, git, operating-system, zlib

I have the following code:

```
import zlib
import os

...

    for current, subs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in files:
            
            # in format ##/#{38}
            
            path = os.path.join(current, filename)[2:]

            # 'info/' and 'pack/' exist
            # don't worry about packed files
            # assume empty (excluding . and ..)

            with open(path, 'r') as file:
                
                # returns bytes object
                # assuming UTF-8 encoding (default) vs. legacy
                # https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion
                # .decode() also defaults to utf-8
                
                print(zlib.decompress(file.read()).decode())
```

where the current directory is `.git/objects/`, and I am receiving the following error:

```
    print(zlib.decompress(file.read()).decode())
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 8: invalid start byte
```

The `.git` directory I am attempting to analyze does not have an alternative encoding method specified.

To be clear, I am attempting to perform the equivalent of `git cat-file` in Python without explicitly using the command.

Reading this blog post: https://matthew-brett.github.io/curious-git/reading_git_objects.html

it seems like they did not even think decoding necessary, but it doesn't work without it for me.

Comment: It is a binary file, open it with `'rb'` and do not `decode`.

Comment: Why does this way work @VPfB ? I need to perform additional parsing on this to extract commit ids and their parents, so it would be helpful to know.

Comment: A binary file is a sequence of bytes (i.e. values between 0 to 255). At the low level, or files are binary. A text is a sequence of characters called string. There are far more characters than 256 in Unicode. A string must be converted to bytes if it needs to be saved to a file or transferred. The reverse process is decoding. Opening a file in binary mode means to read its contents literally, OTOH the text mode means to read and decode on the fly. To answer your question: if you decode bytes to text and those bytes are not a result of encoding text to bytes, you'll get either garbage or errors

Comment: I see. So does `rb` decode ASCII (256) by standard? How does `r` run into errors then, if bytes are only ever 256? Wouldn't they always correspond to some decoding? Garbage would make more sense than error.

Comment: `rb` does not decode at all. Yes, it is like 8-bit ASCII (or latin-1, original ASCII is 7-bit). UTF-8 is now the most common text encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 Look at the table. Some byte sequences are not possible to get in encoding, i.e. they cannot be decoded, those are the errors you were getting.

Comment: If you really mean to do a `git cat-file`, then you need not decode/print what you get from zlib decompress straight. At the beginning of what you get from zlib will be a header before the actual content of the object you are decompressing. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects check *Object Storage*

Comment: I just read that @eftshift0 . I am noticing that the decompressions do not look quite in line, but do you know how to accomplish `git cat-file` correctly in Python?

Comment: @VPfB I still don't quite understand why `r` results in an error though and how `decode()` doesn't function properly here. I've been reading about byte strings, and it seems if git encodes in `UTF-8`, which it does, there should be no problem.

Comment: @user18348324 You are dealing with a compressed file (zlib). To get the text, the unchanged contents must be uncompressed and only then it can be decoded.

Comment: Right, so why was there an error with `zlib.decompress(file.read()).decode()` ?

Comment: Edited: Assuming 'rb' mode: inspect the decompressed data. Was it UTF-8 text?

Comment: I inspected it @VPfB . it seems like my git objects were corrupted. Thanks.

Comment: So when I see `b'A string'`, what decoding system does the binary string use by default?